# Why am I working with two separate python builds on my computer and why can I not install selenium on both?

Tags: python, selenium, package

My apologies in advance if I use any improper terminology, I'm still somewhat of a beginner working with Python. I run MacOS

So I have previously installed python3 on my laptop and I use Sublime Text as my IDE. I want to mess around with manipulating webpages using selenium so I went to terminal and ran:

```
pip install selenium
```

This worked, but in Sublime Text it tells me that I have no module named 'selenium' indicating that it's not installed.

I ran this in both terminal and Sublime Text:

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

Terminal returns:
'Users/name/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3'

Sublime Text returns:
'Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3'

I figure that this is where the problem is, and that I only have selenium installed with one version of python. Any thoughts of how to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

You have python both normally on OS and via Anaconda environment. You need to adjust your editor to use Anaconda environment which is where selenium is installed and terminal uses by default.

This [link](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/sublime/) might be helpful.

I would also suggest to use Anaconda to install packages to keep it consistent.